# Regex to find id in url

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following URL:

http://example.com/product/1/something/another-thing

Although it can also be:

http://test.example.com/product/1/something/another-thing

or

http://completelydifferentdomain.tdl/product/1/something/another-thing

And I want to get the number 1 (id) from the URL using Javascript.

The only thing that would always be the same is `/product`. But I have some other pages where there is also `/product` in the url just not at the start of the path.

What would the regex look like?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Use [`window.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to
   retrieve the current path (excluding
   TLD).
2. Use the JavaScript string
   [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.
3. Use the regex `/^\/product\/(\d+)/` to find a path which starts with /product/, then one or more digits (add `i` right at the end to support case insensitivity).
4. Come up with something like this:

   ```
   var res = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/product\/(\d+)/);
   if (res.length == 2) {
       // use res[1] to get the id.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

`/\/product\/(\d+)/` and obtain `$1`.

Comment: wouldn't that also get: http://example.com/something/product/something-else/another-thing ?

Comment: @Jonathon: sorry for bad example. Wouldn't that also get:  example.com/something/product/1/another-thing? :P

Answer (score 1):

Just, as an alternative, to do this without Regex (though i admit regex is awfully nice here)

```
var url = "http://test.example.com//mypage/1/test/test//test";
var newurl = url.replace("http://","").split("/");
for(i=0;i<newurl.length;i++) {
    if(newurl[i] == "") {
     newurl.splice(i,1);   //this for loop takes care of situatiosn where there may be a // or /// instead of a /
    }
}
alert(newurl[2]); //returns 1
```

Comment: does the search string in the replace function accept an array? For the case I want to go for `https://` in the future?

Comment: @PeeHaa not that i know of, but naturally you can chain another replace function on there `url.replace("http://","").replace("https://","")...`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another option.

```
.match(/\/(\d+)+[\/]?/g)
```

This would return all matches of id's present.

Example:

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:4000/#/trees/8/detail/3';

    // with slashes
    var ids = url.match(/\/(\d+)+[\/]?/g);
    console.log(ids);

    //without slashes
    ids = url.match(/\/(\d+)+[\/]?/g).map(id => id.replace(/\//g, ''));
    console.log(ids);
```

This way, your URL doesn't even matter, it justs retrieves all parts that are number only.

To just get the first result you could remove the `g` modifier:

```
 .match(/\/(\d+)+[\/]?/)
```

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:4000/#/trees/8';


var id = url.match(/\/(\d+)+[\/]?/);
//With and without slashes
console.log(id);
```

The id without slashes would be in the second element because this is the first group found in the full match.

Hope this helps people.
Cheers!