# Anyone know why i cant get the url id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

currently all my previous can get the id with same method but here i cant get the url id ?

pageMore.php is a function page which is use for load more page

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.page-message-container').scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop()>0){
            $('.load-more-data').fadeOut();
        }
        else{
            $('.load-more-data').fadeIn();
        }
    });

    $("#load_more_message").click(function(){
       loadmore(); 
    });
});

function loadmore(){

    var loadmoreoldmessage = document.getElementById("more_message").value;
    var pageID = (location.search.match(/pageID=(\d+)/) || [])[0];

    $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'pageMore.php?'+ pageID,
       data:{
           getresult:loadmoreoldmessage
       },
       success:function(response){
           var loadmore = document.getElementById("chatroom-message-container");
           loadmore.innerHTML = response + loadmore.innerHTML;
           document.getElementById("more_message").value = Number(loadmoreoldmessage)+10;
       }
    });
}
```

i also have put the `$pageID=$_GET['pageID'];` in my pageMore.php

Comment: Can you explain what you need in good English

Comment: please check the edited answer, since you want to pass data via url then use get

Answer (score 0):

**Example:** this should be your ajax call in case you use `type:"get"`

```
$.ajax({
       type:'get',
       url:'pageMore.php?pageID='+ pageID +'&getresult='+loadmoreoldmessage,
       success:function(response){
           var loadmore = document.getElementById("chatroom-message-container");
           loadmore.innerHTML = response + loadmore.innerHTML;
           document.getElementById("more_message").value = Number(loadmoreoldmessage)+10;
       }
    });
```

And in pageMore.php use

```
$pageID=$_GET['pageID'];
$getresult=$_GET['getresult'];
```

**Example:** this should be your ajax call in case you use `type:"post"`

```
$.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'pageMore.php',
       data:{
       pageID:pageID,getresult:loadmoreoldmessage
       },
       success:function(response){
           var loadmore = document.getElementById("chatroom-message-container");
           loadmore.innerHTML = response + loadmore.innerHTML;
           document.getElementById("more_message").value = Number(loadmoreoldmessage)+10;
       }
    });
```

And in pageMore.php use

```
$pageID=$_POST['pageID'];
$getresult=$_POST['getresult'];
```

Regarding your ***pageID*** regex in case it does not work, do check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117501/regex-to-find-id-in-url)

Comment: His pageId regex, returns 'pageID=x', and not just the actual page id (number)

Comment: @omerts there is a nice answer on that part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117501/regex-to-find-id-in-url for the OP to check

Comment: i fixed the problem by myself but still thanks for you answer

Comment: sorry for cant upvote your answer== i didnt have enough reputation